# How do I remove this kitchen faucet?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I Googled a lot, checked a lot of YouTube videos but to no avail.

I have a single hole kitchen faucet.

[image]

The image shows the bottom part of the faucet. I'm not sure what to unscrew. I thought there would be a nut under the metal C shaped cap. But I could not find any nut or anything I can unscrew. I am trying to replace this one with a new one.

My house is somewhat old (20 years).

Comment: The knurled brass piece at the bottom of the picture looks promising.

Comment: Is that solder at the joints that looks like it's dripping down?

Comment: There should NOT be solder at the upper joint. Someone was trying to "tighten" a loose connection.  Is the sink rusting above the faucet connection? Take sink out with faucet attached.

Comment: @Monso, will try the knurled brass piece today and report back. Need to check if its rust.

Comment: Finally got it and replaced. I would have posted the photo of the newly installed faucet if it was allowed :) You gave me new hope @Monso after I gave up. Thank you rest of you for answering. Yes mikes, you are right.

Comment: This question helped me learn a new word today. Knurled. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a similar design at the Delta website. The round knurled piece should unscrew. The male threaded section should also unscrew. Apparently some have a hex shape to facilitate installation. Some have an internal female hex shape that is removed by an allen wrench. This allows the retaining plate to be removed. If there is enough room between the backsplash and the spout you could try holding the piece under the sink with a pipe-wrench, vise grips or large pliers and have someone spin the faucet.